# Android markers not showing up asynctask maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, google-maps-markers

I am trying to get markers to display on a map. It is getting the markers lat and long from a MySQL database and retrieving it using JSON in a asynctask and I'm getting the following in the logs. I am thinking it has to do with the google certificate but I'm not sure. This code does work on older version of android <5 but not newer versions.

```
I/zzbx: Making Creator dynamically
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 11020000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11743470
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=125KB, data=68KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=120KB, data=67KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
I/Choreographer: Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/Google Maps Android API: Deprecation notice: In a future release, indoor will no longer be supported on satellite, hybrid or terrain type maps. Even where indoor is not supported, isIndoorEnabled() will continue to return the value that has been set via setIndoorEnabled(), as it does now. By default, setIndoorEnabled is 'true'. The API release notes (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases) will let you know when indoor support becomes unavailable on those map types.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9a51aee0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9a7ff8a0)

             [ 12-18 19:32:33.017  6391: 6463 D/         ]
             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8abe1340, tid 6463
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x82ad6f60: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x82ad6f60: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0x823a57e0)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
```

here is my code

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements      GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

private Marker marker;
private GoogleMap mMap;
public String lastClick;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    new AsyncTaskGetMareker().execute();
}

public String getJSONFromAssets() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String cID = intent.getStringExtra("cID");
        InputStream inputData = new URL("someurlhere" + cID).openStream();
        int size = inputData.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        inputData.read(buffer);
        inputData.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}




private class AsyncTaskGetMareker extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String stationsJsonString = getJSONFromAssets();
        try {
            JSONArray stationsJsonArray = new JSONArray(stationsJsonString);
            return stationsJsonArray;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //This will only happen if an exception is thrown above:
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        if (result != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    jsonObject = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name= jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String lat = jsonObject.getString("lat");
                    String lng = jsonObject.getString("lng");
                    String occupied = jsonObject.getString("occupied");
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    String hunb = jsonObject.getString("hunb");
                    int occ = Integer.parseInt(occupied);
                    drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),
                            Double.parseDouble(lng)), name, occ, id, hunb);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void drawMarker(LatLng point, String name, int occ, String id, String hunb) {

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(point)
                .title(name)
                .snippet(id)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the api in beginning in onCreate() method so that when your fragments create that time it send the request to server to get the record and the another end google map will ready. please try to apply this logic.

Comment: Are you saying call the asynctask in the oncreate vs the onmapready?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems that you haven't requested Location permission.
It maybe going to the return statement and your asynctask statement on map ready is not being executed.

just check with setting up target_sdk 22 in app gradle.

This is just for testing purpose. You need to do the code for requesting permission before accessing mylocationenabled(true) on map object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the Permission for Location is granted or not.
As you have return statement in your code before execution of the AysncTask It is probably not executing the task.

Try giving permission form Application setting for Location and check if it works.

You should be handling permission for marshmallow onward in your code as well.